# How to do upsert operation using java mongo spark connector and process the data in spark?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Read the CSV file and get the department column from CSV, based on this column  fetch the **"department"** data from mongodb collection having only status ***active***.

After that insert the CSV data by below step in mongodb **"companydetails"** collection.

If *department name* repeated in CSV so that when specific *department name*  is not there in **companydetails** collection then insert the data with additional filed like companyname getting from **department** collection .If *department name* is already there then do update  like by adding one more object to array like employename details of **CCC** shown at end.

CSV file  like below:

```
emlpoyeename,employeeid,joiningdate,salaray,hikedate,department,status

AAA,1,2018-02-15,10$,2019-02-15,EEE,active
BBB,2,2018-02-15,15$,2019-02-15,FFF,active
CCC,3,2018-02-15,15$,2019-02-15,EEE,active
```

MongoDb  collection name **"department"** documents below

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ffc0eeac1e0532f9d4aa4fc"),
    "department" : "EEE",
    "status" : "active",
    "companyName": "OPRA"
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ffc0eeac1e0532f9hjklkc"),
    "department" : "BBB",
    "status" : "inactive",
    "companyName": "ZARR"
}
```

Mongodb  collection name "companydetails" documents below shows for Upsert Operation:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("9ffc0eeac1e0532f9dcfgdhjkl"),
    "department" : "EEE",
    "status" : "active",
    "companyName": "OPRA"
    "employeeDetails":[
    {
    "emlpoyeename": "AAA",
    "employeeid": 1,
    "joiningdate": "2018-02-15",
    "salaray": "10$"
    
    },
        {
    "emlpoyeename": "CCC",
    "employeeid": 1,
    "joiningdate": "2018-02-15",
    "salaray": "15$"
    
    }
    
    ]
}
```